# How can I arrange layers 'forward and backward' in Adobe products?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, adobe-photoshop-elements, shortcuts

In Adobe products are there any shortcut keys to move layers forward and backward instead of dragging layers up and down in the palette to arrange them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are OS dependent, look under `Layer » Arrange`

[image]